# Contact form PHP showing status of 405 method not allowed on IIS

Tags: php, html, forms, iis

I have a template I downloaded and with it came a PHP form. I have tried to fill in the form and send but it does nothing. The console shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of: 405 (Method Not Allowed)

HTML:

```
  <form action="contact-form.php" method="POST" class="contact-form">
                  <ul class="row">
                    <li class="col-md-6 form-item">
                      <label for="contact-name"><i class="ico-male"></i></label>
                      <input type="text" name="contact-name" class="contact-name" id="contact-name" value="Your Name" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Name'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Name')this.value=''">
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-6 form-item">
                      <label for="contact-email"><i class="ico-email"></i></label>
                      <input type="email" name="contact-email" class="contact-email" id="contact-email" value="Your Email" onblur="if(this.value=='')this.value='Your Email'" onfocus="if(this.value=='Your Email')this.value=''">
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-12 form-item">
                      <label for="contact-message"><i class="ico-bubble"></i></label>
                      <textarea name="contact-message" class="contact-message" id="contact-message" data-placeholder="Your message"></textarea>
                    </li>
                    <li class="col-md-12 form-item">
                      <input type="submit" name="contact-btn" class="contact-btn general-link" id="contact-btn" value="Send Your Message">
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </form><!-- end of contact form -->
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if($_POST["submit"]) {

    $fromEmail      =  strip_tags($_POST['contact-email']);
    $fromName       =  strip_tags($_POST['contact-name']);
    $themessage     =  strip_tags($_POST['contact-message']);
    $themessage     =  $themessage."The Sender Is ( ".$fromName." )" ; 



    $toEmail = 'jh@gmail.com';
    $toName = 'JH';

    Mail::send('emails.contactus', $data , function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject)
    {
        $message->to($toEmail, $toName);

        $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

        $message->subject($subject);
    });

$headers = 'From:' .$fromName . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To:' .$fromEmail. "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();



if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $themessage, $headers))
{

      // Send 
echo "success";

}
else{ echo "An error has be occured"; }
}

?>
```

I am doing this locally on IIS server and receiving this.

I have installed PHP and now am receiving this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IIS under your PHP site, go to Handler Mappings and look for the path `*.php` -

You might have multiple mappings for `*.php` check them all, click on edit, then click the request restrictions button, click on the verbs tab. Make sure all verbs is checked or it lists the options `GET,HEAD,POST`

If you didn't install PHP on IIS here's a link: https://php.iis.net/

Comment: Thanks, I installed PHP. But now I receive: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) Can you help?

Comment: Raj, I answered the question why you were getting the 403 error, because you didn't have PHP installed on IIS, please mark it correct and post a new question on why you're getting a 500 error with trying to load a PHP page.  This forum is not meant for trying to solve multiple issues in the same question.  You can add a link to your new question from this one. But I did answer your original question correctly, please mark it as so.